# What is the difference between |$\frac{ d\vec{r}}{dt}$| and $\frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, velocity, displacement

let $\vec{r}$ be the position vector.
$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$ will be the velocity.

But what is the difference between |$\frac{ d\vec{r}}{dt}$| and $\frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}$ ? Do both of them mean the same thing, i.e, magnitude of velocity?

Similarly what is the difference between |$\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$| and $\frac{d|\vec{v}|}{dt}$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/677350/195139

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time derivative of the absolute value of the velocity

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d|\mathbf{v}|}{\mathrm dt}$$

doesn't take into account change of direction of the velocity, i.e. acceleration in directions perpendicular to the motion.

The absolute value of the time derivative of the velocity, i.e. the absolute value of the acceleration

$$\Bigg|\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm dt} \Bigg| = | \mathbf{a}|,$$

does.

As an example, in a uniform circular motion, $\mathbf{v}(t) = V \mathbf{\hat\theta}(t)$, the absolute value  of the velocity, $V$, is constant and thus

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d|\mathbf{v}|}{\mathrm dt}
=\dfrac{\mathrm d|V|}{\mathrm dt} = 0,$$

while the acceleration points towards the centre of the circle and reads $\mathbf{a} = - \frac{V^2}{R} \mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and thus

$$\Bigg|\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm dt} \Bigg|
= \frac{V^2}{R}.$$

**Time derivative of the velocity**

If you write the velocity as the absolute value times a unit vector that indicates the direction of the vector, $\mathbf{v} = v \mathbf{\hat{v}}$, you can write the acceleration as the sum of two contributions, one with the same direction of the velocity and one perpendicular (since $\dfrac{d\mathbf{\hat{v}}}{dt} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{v}} = 0$ for every unit-length vector) to it

$$\mathbf{a}= \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} (v \mathbf{\hat{v}}) =\dfrac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm dt} \mathbf{\hat{v}} + v \dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{\hat{v}}}{\mathrm dt}.$$

If you need to compare the absolute values of your question, we can take the absolute value of the last equation, exploiting that  orthogonality between the two contributions of acceleration and thus Pythagorean theorem

$$|\mathbf{a}|^2 =\Bigg| \dfrac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm dt} \Bigg|^2 + v^2 \Bigg|\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{\hat{v}}}{\mathrm dt}\Bigg|^2   $$.

Comment: I thought "aha, uniform circular motion would be a good illustration of the difference" - and there it is in a answer posted 2 minutes ago !

Comment: thanks  a lot. one doubt though, what will be the  difference between dv/dt and |dv/dt|? could use this case as an example?

Comment: I'm editing my answer

Comment: what does it mean if acceleration is = + V^2/R ? like in the case above it was negative so we had a uniform circular motion. If it becomes negative then will we still have uniform circular motion?

Comment: @Obinna acceleration is a vector. Using polar coordinates to describing the motion,  if the acceleration of a point with constant azimuthal velocity points in positive radial direction, you don't have circular motion

Comment: what about gravity? during projectile motion, our teacher taught us that $\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$ was g with an arrow pointed downwards. so will mod of this become just g?

Comment: your teacher is right. But now, we're going off-topics, w.r.t. your question. If the answer to your original question is fine, please accept the answer. If you have any other doubt, please ask new questions

Comment: Thank you so much!