# Derivative of distance

Tags: classical-mechanics, calculus, speed, distance, displacement

I know that $speed = |\frac{\vec{dr}}{dt}|$
and first derivative of distance with respect time will be $\frac{d\vec{|r|}}{dt}|$

These 2 expressions don't seem to represent the same thing. But when I draw displacement-time graphs and distance-time graphs for a particle in a single direction(it later returns too), I can understand that the slope of distance-time graph is equal to the speed. I am confused whether this will happen for 1D motion only or any case.

I will be grateful if you help me

Comment: see also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/677350/is-the-derivative-of-the-magnitude-of-a-position-vector-the-speed-is-the-integr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically:

$$|\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}| =|\vec{v}|=v \ ,\ \text{meanwhile} \ \frac{d|\vec{r}|}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}$$

That is, the second expression is simply the rate of change of the magnitude of the position vector. That's why, in uniform circular motion, the second expression is $0$: a circle has a fixed magnitude and thus $dr/dt=0$.

EDIT: 1D motion is essentially the same as working with scalars, therefore in that case the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell whether it will be correct to say that derivative of distance equation gives the radial component of velocity in 2-D motion